# Bash al (alias local) function not found

Tags: bash, alias

Can I have bash aliases local to directory?

Given such directory structure:

```
dir1/
  - .
  - ..
  - dir2/
  - file
```

When I `cd dir1` alias `eg` do not work, but when I `cd dir1/dir2/` such alias works. Definition of alsias also should be local, residing in `dir1/dir2/`

*Use case:*
I'm programmer with many different companion tools to my projects. I would like to make aliases for some of them, but most of those would be **project/directory** specific.

I've seen `al` bash command that would acomplish this, but it's not present in my Ubuntu (14.04).

Comment: What is your question? If I answer your statements: 1.Yes it is possible, using bash's `alias` builtin. 2. What are "al bash application" and ".al"? Something local to your site?. 3. They might, locally. "Ubuntu" is not a monolith - it can be customized. What version (`uname -a`) are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The simplest approach would be to have a file where your aliases are defined in each directory. So, for example:

```
$ cat dir1/.alias
alias eg='echo "this is dir1"'
$ cat dir2/.alias
alias eg='echo "this is dir2"'
```

In the example above, each directory contains a file called `.alias` where the `eg` alias is defined. Now, `cd` into one of them, [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) the file, and the alias becomes available:

```
$ cd dir1 && source .alias
$ eg
This is dir1
$ cd ../dir2 && source .alias
$ eg
This is dir2
```

If you want this done automatically, add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
## Check if an '.alias' file exists and, if it does, source it. 
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -e .alias ] && source .alias'
```

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable defines a command that is executed before each prompt is shown, so after any command you run. This means that as soon as you more into a directory that contains an `.alias` file, this file will be sourced.

#### Notes

- This is insecure. Any code within the `.alias` file will be executed. Use at your own risk. The manual approach is much safer.
- Any aliases defined in the `.alias` file will still be available after you leave the directory, until they are overwritten by another alias definition with the same name. If that is a problem, you can clear all aliases and then re-load your global ones with:

  ```
  unalias -a && . /etc/bash.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bash_aliases
  ```

  To simplify it, make it a function by adding these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  clear_aliases(){ 
      unalias -a && . /etc/bash.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bash_aliases; 
  }
  ```

  You will then be able to run `clear_aliases` to reset your defaults.

Comment: A) ~/.bashrc should also contain that command without '' so when opening terminal in such folder it will still work? B) can I add clear_aliases() and somehow alias cd so that cd will call clear_aliases() for me when exiting such folder?

Comment: @przemo_li yes, that would work. It's a bit of unnecessary overhead but it should work OK.

Comment: @przemo_li sorry, you changed your comment to something else after I answered it. I don't understand A), what command without `"`? Don't really understand what you mean by B) either, it might be easier to ask a new question.